# Cors error while using angular with node js

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN stack project, while communicating with node js API call I am getting an error
as follows.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5050/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But I have already enabled CORS follows.

```
// require .env
require('dotenv').config();
// requring modules
const express=require('express');
const cors=require('cors');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');



const port=5050

// initialize express application
const app=new express();

// configure application
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors());
```

What may be the issue here?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const app = express();` instead of `const app=new express();`

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue, but can you explain what was the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Need to add  proxy to angular code as well .You can find detailed steps [here](https://alexxsanya.medium.com/fix-cors-in-angular-8-using-cli-proxy-configuration-787589f06f94)

```
{
        "/api": {
            "target": "http://localhost:5000",
            "secure": false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

express is a `factory` function, not a `constructor` function. It should be called like a normal function, not used with `new`.

You can see the code for it right [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L37)

So you have to write

`const app = express();`

instead of `const app=new express();`

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS via proxy configuration, we need to generate a src/proxy.conf.json file inside the Angular root folder and also place the following code inside of it.

```
{
"/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
}
}
```

Define Proxy Configuration values in angular.json
To register a proxy configuration, we need to go to the angular.json file and place the following code inside the serve/options. It will set the src/proxy.conf.json file in our Angular app.

```
"architect": {
"serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
        "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project-name:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
        },
      }
 }
```

Now, you are all set to start the dev server with the current proxy configuration, run the given below command. Please restart the server if you make any updates to your proxy conf file.

```
ng serve --open
```

Enable CORS in Node/Express Server
Now, we will learn how to enable CORS in the Express and Node js app. We will look at one of the most straightforward methods to configure CORS in the express by using a third-party package.

You can run the following command to add the cors package in node/express backend.

```
npm install cors --save
```

Next, you can add the below code to enable cors in Express server.

```
// server.js

 const express = require('express');
 const cors = require('cors');
 const app = express();

 app.use(cors());

 /* server configuration here */
```

Finally, CORS is enabled in the node server.

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header will be rendered when any request is made to your application. This header chooses which origin are authorized to access the server resources with CORS.

Here * wildcard allots access from any source.